Opening of device memory in Green Hills System's Integrity RTOS
I am migrating a code from Linux to ghs Integrity Real Time OS. The code requires opening physical/main memory and then map the physical to virtual memory using mmap.
In Linux, main memory is accessed by,
fd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDONLY); 
void * virt_addr = mmap(NULL, 0x20000, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, physical_addr);

int32_t register_access = ((UINT8 *)virt_addr + 0x2000);

Note: physical_addr is a physical address of base address register(BAR) in PCI.
Can you please let me know how this can be accomplished in Integrity?
I have implemented this in vxWorks code is:
/* lukup table idx 0 */
    ret = idt_ntb_peer_mw_get_addr(&ndev->ntb, 0, &ndev->outMemAddr, &ndev->sizeMapReg);

ret = devMemCreate("/sw2NTB1Cfg", 0, (PHYS_ADDR)ndev->outMemAddr, ndev->sizeMapReg, MMU_ATTR_SUP_RW | MMU_ATTR_USR_RW |
            MMU_ATTR_VALID | MMU_ATTR_CACHE_OFF);

/*Opening device memory */
fd = devMemOpen("/sw2NTB1Cfg", O_RDWR, S_IRWXU);

/*mapping physical to virtual using mmap*/
ndev->sw2Ntb1regAddr = mmap(0, 0x200000, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);

/*Accessing SW2 NTB device id(offset = 0x2000) using this addr*/
memcpy(&data, (UINT8 *)ndev->sw2Ntb1regAddr + reg, 4);  //reg is offset

How will I implement this in Green Hills System's Integrity RTOS.

"Opening of device memory ..." - You seem to be conflating the first step in a procedure with the purpose of that procedure. You also seem to not grasp the implications of that procedure. IOW such a mapping grants from userspace access to hardware device registers, which potentially can break the system. Such access is a kludge intended for testing, and should be avoided for a robust system. "Device memory" and registers are best managed by kernel drivers. An RTOS that emphasizes Safe, Secure, Reliable might not even provide such risky privileges.

Hi @sawdust,   It is PCI NTB driver between two PCI NTB switch. and I am trying to access SW2 NTB switch registers to configure communication between them. For this, Physical to virtual mapping needs to be done. Please help me on this, how should I try implement this.

Looks like you need a real driver for that.

I am using PCI NTB device driver.
